# How can i fix hydration error in Next.js?

Tags: next.js13

I tried to add a theme toggle component in my Next.js project however im experiencing an hydration error issue. Can someone help me out

```
"use client";

import { MoonIcon, SunIcon } from "@heroicons/react/24/outline";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

export default function DarkModeToggle() {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (darkMode) {
      document.documentElement.classList.add("dark");
    } else {
      document.documentElement.classList.remove("dark");
    }
  }, [darkMode]);
  return (
    <button
      className="p-1 rounded-lg hover:text-[#f6f6f9] dark:hover:text-[#181a1e] hover:bg-[#181a1e] dark:hover:bg-[#f6f6f9] transition-all duration-75 ease-in-out"
      onClick={() => setDarkMode(!darkMode)}
    >
      {darkMode ? (
        <SunIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
      ) : (
        <MoonIcon className="w-5 h-5" />
      )}
    </button>
  );
}
```

Comment: In your `useEffect` would you like to check `if (typeof window !== "undefined") {...}` because of [Hydration errors can occur from](https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/react-hydration-error#common-causes)